# How do I avoid popping up an error dialog when my MSVS C++ app crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When my Visual Studio 2008 C++ command-line application crashes, it sometimes produces this dialog.

*CommandProcessor.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.*

*We are sorry for the inconvenience. If you were in the middle of something, the information you were working on might be lost. For more informaiton about this error, click here.*

I tried this in Release and in Debug mode.

(By the way, the debugger shows that this is a divide by zero error.)

If it is going to crash, I don't want this dialog, which blocks the application. How do I compile my application so that crashes do not produce the dialog?

Comment: how come a post-mortem dialog blocks an already-dead application?

Comment: Ironically that is true - the program is close to being finished but a message box is there. That's a huge problem for automated builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With /EHa option you can use catch(...) to catch all exceptions included structured exceptions and write a console message. You can also use VC++ - specific __try for structured exception handling instead, but that's a bit harder to code.

However this will not protect you against situations when terminate() is called by the C++ runtime - like when an exception escapes a destructor during stack unwinding - you will also have to change the terminate() handler by calling set_terminate().

Comment: /EHa is best set through Project -> Properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable c++ exceptions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623373/catching-exception-in-code

Answer (score 4):

Read series of articles [Exception Handling and Crash Reporting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/XCrashReportPt1.aspx). It is possible to catch exception and process it as you wish (you can save crash dump for instance).